# Regex: How to get everything within brackets before a certain character?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, python-2.7

How would I return a string within brackets after a certain character? I am interested in the string before `|#|` within the brackets `()`. Given two strings:

```
s1 = 'This is the part of the string not of interest LEMB(INTEREST)|#|IND'
s2 = 'someotherstring(NOT_OF_INTEREST)
```

I tried with this regular expression

```
pattern = r'(?=\#\|IND)\((.*?)\)'
results = re.findall(pattern,s1)
results[0][0]
```

should return

```
'INTEREST'
```

while `results = re.findall(pattern,s2)` should return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to match the first part and then use a capturing group to capturing what is in between the parenthesis. Then make sure that what follows is `|#|IND`

```
\(([^()]+)\).*?\|#\|IND
```

That will match

- `\(` Match (
- `([^()]+)` Capture in a group matching not `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match )
- `.*?` If there can be anything after the last closing parenthesis then match that
- `\|#\|IND` Match |#|IND

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EF6X4V/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IaOdJ2)

If the last part should immediately be after the closing parenthesis, use

```
\(([^()]+)\)\|#\|IND
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex,

```
(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\)\|#\|)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\()` - This positive look behind ensures data is preceded by a literal `(`
- `[^)]*` - Captures data of your interest
- `(?=\)\|#\|)` - Positive look ahead to ensure it is followed by a closing `)` and literal `|#|`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3tmnTY/1)**

Sample Python codes,

```
import re

arr = ['This is the part of the string not of interest LEMB(INTEREST)|#|IND','someotherstring(NOT_OF_INTEREST)']

for s in arr:
 m = re.search(r'(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\)\|#\|)',s)
 if (m):
  print(s,' --> ',m.group())
 else:
  print(s,' --> No Match')
```

Prints,

```
This is the part of the string not of interest LEMB(INTEREST)|#|IND  -->  INTEREST
someotherstring(NOT_OF_INTEREST)  --> No Match
```